# How to add category name of product as a class in body element

Tags: magento-2.1, php, category-products

I have single product page on my site. The product is having category **"beauty"**.

Product display page having following body tag:

```
<body data-container="body" class="catalog-product-view product-extra-firming-night">
```

body tag have classes -: `catalog-product-view product-extra-firming-night`

Now what I want? I want to add/insert additional class in body tag. (see body tag below).

```
<body data-container="body" class="catalog-product-view product-extra-firming-night current-category-beauty">
```

My workaround is as follows:

I have checked the code in following file. Check the if condition.

[https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php#L162][1]

Also tried to add custom code above if condition.

```
$pageConfig->addBodyClass('product-' . $product->getCategory());
```

Can anybody help on this issue. how to add category name as a class in body tag??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow these steps :

1.Create your own module ( example :Vendor/Mysample)

2.app/code/Vendor/Mysample/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_Mysample" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

3.Create file under  app/code/Vendor/Mysample/etc/frontend/di.xml and copy this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page">
<plugin name="mySampleResultPage" type="Vendor\Mysample\Plugin\Result\Page"/>
</type>

</config>
```

4.Create the registration file app/code/Vendor/Mysample/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Vendor_Mysample',
__DIR__
);
```

5.Create the file app/code/Vendor/Mysample/Plugin/Result/Page.php and copy the below code :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Mysample\Plugin\Result;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

class Page
{
  private $context;
  private $registry;

  public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
  \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
  ) {
     $this->context = $context;
     $this->registry = $registry;
  }

  public function beforeRenderResult(
  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $subject,
  ResponseInterface $response
  ){

  $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');

  if($this->context->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'){
     $subject->getConfig()->addBodyClass('current-category-'.$category->getName());
  }

  return [$response];
  }
}
```

6. run php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Good luck and happy coding !!!

Comment: Sami, I will try this solution and will let u know.....

Comment: @rk1990 , i tested it and it works ;) . Instead of Vendor/Mysample , you can choose the naming like you want

Comment: ok ... i will try this ...

Comment: Hi sami, thanks,  this working for me ... But, the only issue is when i click on product under root category then it gives error "unable to handle request" .. 

For e,g I have root category "Beauty". When i click on product listed under "Beauty" it gives me error.

but when I click on product under "Beauty -> Skincare" it works for me...

any suggetion??

Comment: @rk1990 can you give more details eg pic to can reproduce the error

Comment: HI sami, I am not able to attache image in comment ... so I am attahcing as answer ... after that I will delete the same...

Comment: @rk1990  , you can delete the image that you attach

Comment: @rk1990 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81753/discussion-between-sami23-and-rk1990).

Comment: Hi sami, can you please help me for https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239438/how-to-call-function-from-php-file-to-phtml-file-in-magento-2/239440

Comment: Doesn't work if you navigate straight to a product page url (i.e. not via categories pages). 'Call to a member function getName() on null' ($category == null)  
Also Magento\Registry is now apparently deprecated https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Comment: I ended up using "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView"

Answer (score 0):

We can use event `layout_load_before` to add css class based on current category.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="Innoppl_Test" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Bodycss" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Bodycss.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Bodycss implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $config;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $request;
    protected $categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ){
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        $controller = $this->request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $this->request->getActionName();
        $route      = $this->request->getRouteName();
//      check - is this category page
        if($route == "catalog" && $controller == "category" && $action == "view")
        {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->request->getParam("id"));
            $this->config->addBodyClass("current-category".$category->getName());
        }        

    }

}
```

I have tested, it works [image: Easy for your reference]

Comment: Bilal, app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml.. means you are saying to create custom extension?  or should I change code in file,   app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/frontend/events.xml   and create new php file under app/code/Magento/Catalog/observer... please guide....

Comment: I am new to magento... so i am little bit confused with file name you mentioned above...   it your answer demands to create new extension or should i change code in existing file...  Bodycss.php is custom file????   please guide...

Comment: Thanks, Bilal,  this is works for me ... but only on category page.. I want to display category name also on single product page... Can you please help?