# How to call function from php file to .phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, php, newsletter

I am trying to add google reCaptcha for the newsletter.

I have added the following code after `<form>`;

```
<button
class="g-recaptcha"
data-sitekey="6Lfc-WsUAAAAAMvtAnrdwdDGxdiOsuPyFK4wse1D"
data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn">
Submit
</button>
```

I want to call `subscribe()` function for parameter **data-callback** from file `app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

How to call function from php to .phtml?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inject Subscriber object to your block.
2. From file .phtml (template) call `$block->subscribe()`

Comment: I have tried,   $subscribe  = \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;  then,  $subscribe->subscribe(); it is not working

Comment: No. inject Subscriber object  to your block object. or using object Manager for create Subscriber instance

Comment: Example:
`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$subscribe = $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber');
$subscribe->subscribe();` //it works but not recommend